# How to call some method as soon as my UITextField length reaches 6 characters

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to perform some action when my textField character count becomes 6 in swift.

Comment: use UITextField/UITextView Delegate Methods

Comment: refere to official documentations of UITextField/UITextView

Answer (score 4):

Use the delegate

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

and then implement

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
     if textField.text?.characters.count == 6 {
       // Call some method
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` to get length as well as position using range.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

   let text = (textField.text ?? "") as String
   let txtAfterUpdate = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
   if (text.characters.count == 6 && range.location > 5) {
        return false // if you want to restrict your string length of call some method here
   }
   return true
}
```